How can I split this data into rows in a data frame with column names with pandas?
Each row of my data looks something like this:
8,0    0        1     0.000000000  8082  A  WS 24664872 + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576

I'd like to split the data into columns like this:
col1   col2     col3  col4         col5  col6 col7 col8      col9
8,0    0        1     0.000000000  8082  A    WS   24664872  + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576

I'm new to data processing in python and have no idea how to correctly delimit the columns. Current code I'm using uses chunking because of large file size:
import pandas as pd
file_path = "test_data.txt"
chunk_size = 1000000
# column_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

df_list = []

for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=chunk_size):
    df_list.append(chunk)

df = pd.concat(df_list)

for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)


Is it fixed width?  Tab delimited? Delimited by some funky hidden character?

Assuming a list of strings as input, you could use re.split with a maximum number of splits (here 8):
import re

data = ['8,0    0        1     0.000000000  8082  A  WS 24664872 + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576',
        '8,0    0        2     0.000000000  8082  A  WS 24664872 + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576',
       ]

colnames = [f'col{x+1}' for x in range(9)]

df = pd.DataFrame((re.split(' +', s, maxsplit=8) for s in data),
                  columns=colnames # optional
                 )

Output:
  col1 col2 col3         col4  col5 col6 col7      col8                   col9
0  8,0    0    1  0.000000000  8082    A   WS  24664872  + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576
1  8,0    0    2  0.000000000  8082    A   WS  24664872  + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576

If you want to benefit from pandas import features, you could also convert to CSV with re.sub and use read_csv:
import re
import io

data = ['8,0    0        1     0.000000000  8082  A  WS 24664872 + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576',
        '8,0    0        2     0.000000000  8082  A  WS 24664872 + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576',
       ]

colnames = [f'col{x+1}' for x in range(9)]

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join([re.sub(' +', ',', s, count=8) for s in data])),
                 names=colnames # optional
                )

NB. this second approach assumes a simple CSV format, without pre-existing , or quoted characters.

From the example line you provided, it looks that we can simply split by whitespace and then concatenate the 8: parts (8-th element onwards). To gain some intuition, you might try the following snippet which achieves what you want with a string:
import pandas as pd

data_string = "8,0    0        1     0.000000000  8082  A  WS 24664872 + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576"
parts = data_string.split()  # Split the string by whitespace
result = pd.Series(parts[:8] + [" ".join(parts[8:])])

print(result)

# Output:
# 0    8,0
# 1     0
# 2     1
# 3     0.000000000
# 4     8082
# 5     A
# 6     WS
# 7    24664872
# 8    + 8 <- (8,2) 23604576
# dtype: object

Now, we can translate this to pandas, with a little bit of tweaking using pandas.Series.str:
file_path = "test_data.txt"
chunk_size = 1000000

df_list = []

for chunk in pd.read_csv(
    file_path,
    chunksize=chunk_size,
    header=None,
    engine="python",
    delimiter="\t",  # This should make all lines be loaded as a single column
):
    chunk_df = chunk[0].str.split(expand=True, n=8) # Only 8 columns

    # Append modified chunk to the list
    df_list.append(chunk_df)

# Concatenate all chunks into a single DataFrame
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

df.head(10)

This should give you something like this:

Note that the whole idea is to load the chunk as a single column DataFrame, so that we can split it after. The first line inside the loop:chunk_df = chunk[0].str.split(expand=True, n=8) gives you the 8 columns correctly per chunk. Note the n=8 argument (thanks @mozway for the idea), which specifies the number of max splits, similar to re.split(maxsplit=8).
